# external performClick() on android

Tags: java, android

I want to `performClick()` to coordinates on android. it should be able to interact external apps. similar to the ghost mouse on windows.

Answer (score 1):

you can inject touch events to the system, here is a tutorial about this

http://www.pocketmagic.net/2012/04/injecting-events-programatically-on-android/

Comment: Fortunately, the techniques outlined in that blog post only work on rooted devices.

Comment: as I unserstand first 2 doesnt work on externals because android developers forbided. and 3rd works if you have root access?

Comment: app will be in a local use I can live with root access.